# find and replace in in multiple files

Tags: .net, windows, iis-7, batch-file

I am using IIS7 and have multiple folders (individual web pages based on HTML5) published. every folder has a file named "cache.manifest" and I want to find a specific string (javascript file name) and replace the with my new string.

I have more than 1000 folders and want to automate this.

I am looking for a .net or similar code that will do this for me. I have access to the folder so I can even run an EXE to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
for /r "start folder" %%a in (cache.manifest*) do (
    if "%%~nxa"=="cache.manifest" sed -i.bak "s/find/replace/g" "%%~fa"
)
```

With the parameter `-i.bak` sed makes a backup copy.